# Data binding in java oveeriding

Tags: java, polymorphism

I am beginner for java.I have written following code

```
class SuperA{
  Integer a = 1;
  protected void f(){
    System.out.println("in superA");
  }
}

class Test extends SuperA{
  Integer a = 2;
  protected void f(){
    System.out.println("in test");
  }

  public static void main(String... args) throws Exception{   

    SuperA o = new Test();
    o.f();
    System.out.println("a = "+o.a);
  }
}
```

> **Output:** in test
>
> a = 1

I know why it is `in test`.But didnt get why `a=1`. I thought that it should be `a=2`.

**What is difference calling method and data in polymorphism?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class SuperA{
  Integer a = 1;
```

---

```
class Test extends SuperA{
  Integer a = 2;
```

---

Your `Test` class posseses two independent instance variables named `a`. They are accessible as

```
this.a
```

and

```
((SuperA)this).a
```

That makes them different from methods, where `f()` defined in `Test` *overrides* the  one in `SuperA`, so `Test` does not posses the superclass version.

Comment: So you are saying only behavior is overridden not data?

Comment: Overriding data is meaningless, anyway: you can't change anything by overriding it.

Answer (score 1):

**Runtime Polymorphism** doesn't apply on data variables i.e **a** in your case so when you try to print **o.a** it will check the reference variable type that is **SuperA** in this case so o/p would be 1 not 2. 
follow link for details--> [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/polymorphism.html)

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend that you do this:

```
class SuperA {
  protected Integer a = 1;

  protected void f() {
    System.out.println("in superA");
  }
}

class Test extends SuperA {
  private static final Integer DEFAULT_A = 2;

  public Test() {
    super(DEFAULT_A);
  }

  protected void f(){
    System.out.println("in test");
  }
}
```

Comment: No.I am not want solution over this but just want to know how mapping is done between object on stack and heap.some lower view.